What is the figure of speech scheme name for "X and Y, Y and X"?
I would like to properly classify a figure of speech that can be generalized as "X and Y, Y and X". Here is a specific example randomly generated by my imagination: "Honey and berries, berries and honey. This is what every respectable bear values the most, my friend!".
On the top level, I know it is a scheme, not a trope. But when I am looking at the list of figure of speech schemes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_of_speech#Schemes), I can't seem to find a good match.
Also, a related question: does anyone know a historical origin of this scheme and especially is any historical villains have tarnished it by using it? I doubt that I am an original inventor of this scheme and it definitely feels like I have heard it somewhere before.
